# Why am I getting a MissingAuthenticationToken error when calling sns.publish from Python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm working on a Python 3.10.3 application in a Docker container that sends messages using AWS SNS. I've written this code:

```py
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
config = Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)

def send_sns_message(topic_arn: str, message: str, message_attributes: dict) -> None:
    sns = boto3.client(
        "sns",
        region_name=os.environ["AWS_REGION"],
        aws_access_key_id= os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
        config=config,
    )
    att_dict = {}
    for key, value in message_attributes.items():
        if isinstance(value, str):
            att_dict[key] = {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": value}
    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn=topic_arn,
        Message=message,
        MessageGroupId=str(uuid4()),
        MessageAttributes=att_dict,
    )
```

When I call this function with a valid topic_arn, message and message_attributes it generates this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MissingAuthenticationToken) when calling the Publish operation: Request is missing Authentication Token
```

The AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are valid. Does anyone have any suggestion about how I can resolve this issue? Or, where to find/generate an authentication token?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, sometimes I hates me some AWS. I took out the `config` option and now things are working fine.
This falls under the big NEVERMIND sign!